# Accessing Shared Mailbox sub folders with exchangelib python

Tags: python-3.5, exchangelib

I am trying to use `exchangelib` in order to monitor an e-mail address from a dedicated server without requiring an instance of Outlook be installed. We want to move the emails to a processed subfolder once completed. I have been able to connect to the shared mailbox and see the e-mails within the inbox. When I am trying to move the e-mail to the sub folder I am receiving the error. I used `exchangelib` to create the subfolder and can see it within outlook and OWA.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
def _move_to_processed(item):
    processed_folder = account.inbox / 'Processed_Test'
    item.move(processed_folder)
```

**Error message:**

```
raise ErrorFolderNotFound("No subfolder with name '%s'" % other)
exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound: No subfolder with name 'Processed_Test'
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace? I assume the exception is caused by line 2, but it's nice to be sure. Also, that line will only work if `a.root.tree()` contains a folder called `Processed_Test` at the location you specified.

Comment: File "C:\email.py", line 198, in <module>
    mailbox_helper().scan_inbox()                                                  File "C:\email.py", line 99, in scan_inbox
    self.__move_to_processed(item)
File "C:\email.py", line 70, in _move_to_processed
    processed_folder = self.account.inbox / 'Processed Folder'
File "email.py", line 844, in __truediv__
    raise ErrorFolderNotFound("No subfolder with name '%s'" % other)
exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound: No subfolder with name 'Processed Folder'

Comment: @ErikCederstrand : The folder does not show during a.root.tree().  It is showing the folders within my account, not the shared account.  Would there be another way to navigate to processed folder?

Comment: Ah. I think that bug was fixed in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/commit/71def9d94220eb639241b6a56a164cf4b7b9b593 which is not in any release yet. You could try installing from GitHub and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: That fixed the issue!  The process can find the Processed Folder within the Shared Mailbox, and move items to it.  Thank you very much for your help!